# RSS Feed-based emails not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, content-area

we implemented a RSSFeed Newsletter for our magazine.

It was working without problem since today when we start to got errors message during the call data.

I tried to figure out which kind of problem we have but it seems to me everything fine.

How I can figure out which problem do we have?

Here the Email calling from a content area

```
%%[

var @rssInput, @titles, @subtitles, @links, @guids, @pubDates, @creators, @descriptions, @images, @contents, @rowCount, @title, @subtitle, @link, @guid, @pubDate, @creator, @description, @image, @content, @pubDateDay, @pubDateMonth, @pubDateMonthChar, @pubDateYear, @pubDateHour, @pubDateMinute, @pubDateSecond, @pubDateTimezone, @pubDateOriginal, @pubDateParseString, @pubDateHourChar, @pubDatePA, @pubDateTimezoneRaw

set @rssInput = ContentAreaByName("my contents\RSSFeedsImport\DNP_NewsfeedRSS")
set @DEname = "RSSFeedImport_DNP"

set @rssInput = Replace(@rssInput,"atom:","")

set @items = BuildRowsetFromXML(@rssInput,"//item",1)
set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@rssInput,"//item/title",1)
set @subtitles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@rssInput,"//item/subtitle",1)
set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@rssInput,"//item/link",1)
set @guids = BuildRowsetFromXML(@rssInput,"//item/guid",1)
set @pubDates = BuildRowsetFromXML(@rssInput,"//item/pubDate",1)
set @descriptions = BuildRowsetFromXML(@rssInput,"//item/description",1)
set @images = BuildRowsetFromXML(@rssInput,"//item/enclosure",1)

set @rowCount = RowCount(@titles)

if @rowCount != rowcount(@images) then

]%%
```

---

And here the content area

```
%%before; httpget; 1 "http://www.dotnetpro.de/rssfeed_standard_data_919966.html"%%
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please update you question to include the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I try to leverage XPATH a little more when parsing XML.  The important part is within the loop you should be checking the rowcount on each element.

```
%%[

/* set @rss = ContentAreaByName("my contents\RSSFeedsImport\DNP_NewsfeedRSS") */
set @rss = httpget("http://www.dotnetpro.de/rssfeed_standard_data_919966.html",true)
set @rss = Replace(@rss,"atom:","")

/* 
output(concat("<br>rssInput: <br>",replace(replace(@rss,">","&gt;"),"<","&lt;") ))
*/

set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@rss,"//item",0)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

set @maxToDisplay = 999

set @rowCount = iif(@rowCount > @maxToDisplay, @maxToDisplay, @rowCount)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @title
    var @pubDate

    if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@rss,concat("//item[",@i,"]/title"),0)) > 0 then
        set @title = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@rss,concat("//item[",@i,"]/title"),0),1),'Value')
    endif

    if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@rss,concat("//item[",@i,"]/pubDate"),0)) > 0 then
        set @pubDate = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@rss,concat("//item[",@i,"]/pubDate"),0),1),'Value')
    endif

    outputline(concat("<br><br>title: ", @title))
    outputline(concat("<br>pubDate: ", @pubDate))

  next @i

else

  raiseerror("no items found")

endif

]%%
```

I'd suggest adding your content area retrieve back in after you're satisfied with the results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a server issue. Now is working everything fine again.

This is the answer I got from Salesforce:

> Please go through following error which I got from back end.
>
> MachineName: ATL1S07MAIL0522 MemberID: 7224959 JobID: 3449939 OMMSlotID 112513618 
>   ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a SubString function call. See inner exception for details. 
>   Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR 
>   - from OMMCommon -->
>
> --- inner exception 1---
>
> --- Stack Trace (inner exception 1) ---
>
> at ExactTarget.OMM.ResolvedParameter.GetInvalidParameterException(String etSource, FunctionInvokeContext invokeContext, String message) 
>   at ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionHandler.InvokeSubstring(ResolvedFunction resolvedFunction, FunctionInvokeContext invokeContext, FunctionReturnInformation& returnInfo)
>
> --- Stack Trace ---
>
> The error seems like temporary server error. Let me know if you have further concern.

The error was affected only one automation and only for one weekend.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Imagine if someone else faces the same issue as you down the road. Do you think this answer would be helpful to them?